# SQL function - Split a number into part count

Tags: sql, math

I want to split a number into parts(buckets).

For example when I split a number 13 by 4, expected output is 4 bucket (4,4,4,1)

13 split by 4 parts -> **4 (Expected output)**

For example when I split a number 11 by 4, expected output is 3 bucket (4,4,3)

11 split by 4 parts -> **3 (Expected output)**

For example when I split a number 3 by 4, expected output is 1 bucket
3 split by 4 parts -> **1 (Expected output)**

How do I do this in SQL function

Comment: Why have tagged Oracle and SQL Server?

Comment: @BalajiSrinivasan . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Also sample data and desired results -- as *text tables* -- would really help.  SQL has no construct called a "bucket" or "part" so the question is unclear.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use next Code for retrieving the buckets and the count:-

```
Declare 
    @InputNumber int, 
    @SplitBy int, 
    @Count int, 
    @Buckets VARCHAR(1000)

Set @InputNumber = 14
Set @SplitBy = 4
Set @Count = 0 

While @InputNumber > @SplitBy
Begin
    Set @Buckets = Convert(Varchar(10),@SplitBy) + ',' + isNULL( @Buckets,'')
    Set @InputNumber = @InputNumber - @SplitBy
    Set @Count =  @Count + 1
End

Select @Buckets +  Convert(Varchar(10),@InputNumber% @SplitBy) as Buckets , @Count + 1 as Count
```

**Output:-**

```
Buckets    Count
4,4,4,2     4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
DECLARE @Number INT = 13, @Devided INT = 4, @Count INT = 0

WHILE (@Number >= @Devided)   
BEGIN  
    set @Count = @Count + 1;
    set @Number = @Number - @Devided
    print @Devided
END

IF(@Number < @Devided)
BEGIN
    Set @Count = @Count + 1;
    print @Number
END

SELECT  @Count
```

If you just want to count, you can try this way, [demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c12dd43d5be59f28104e0357c5c80055)

```
DECLARE @Number INT = 13, @Devided INT = 4, @Count INT

SET @Count = (@Number / @Devided)

IF(@Number % @Devided <> 0)
BEGIN
    Set @Count = @Count + 1;
END

SELECT  @Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what exactly you're looking for, but using SQL functions only, here is one way. Try plugging in different numbers.

```
declare @num integer;
set @num=11;
select @num, concat(replicate('4,',floor(@num/4)),@num%4), floor(@num/4)+1;
```